# Newsletters blocks should be merged on Email Settings page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page, newsletter

There are two distinct blocks named “Newsletters” on the Email Settings page of the user profile:

> [image: 2 news]

I think they should be merged into one block. Also I noticed that top block has dot in description, but the bottom hasn’t.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for the heads up; that should never have been like that in the first place. We're planning to release an improved newsletter management screen in January and that inadvertently slipped by!

I just pushed a fix to address the duplicate entry.